# EE3 breadcrumb solutions

Tags: navigation, ee3

Before upgrading my company's instance of EE to v3 I used [Crumbly](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/crumbly), which works extremely well for breadcrumb generation.

However it isn't compatible with v3 and I've been unable to find a replacement. How can I go about getting this functionality back, whether through an addon or programatically?

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started an EE3 project. I personally like NavEE. They have a version for EE3 now [here](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/navee-for-expressionengine-3). Not only does it make navigations easier to manage and customize, but it also creates great dynamic breadcrumbs and sitemaps.